# How can I force the site to never come up in the old mobile view?

Tags: support, design, user-interface, mobile-web, mobile-safari

Ever since the new view was pushed to the /questions pages, those pages have started randomly coming up in the old deprecated mobile view on various sites I visit, forcing me to constantly have to navigate to the bottom of the page and try to poke that itty-bitty <sub><sup>"full site"</sup></sub> link without fat-fingering the other links.

Am I blowing away a cookie somewhere that I could keep? I use a VPN, is that causing the problem? A while back, I thought the full site view was going to be changed to be the default, and it seemed like it worked that way until recently.

I use Safari and some browsers that are probably not supported. I looked over [Permanently Force Mobile View on Stack Exchange Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357475/273494) but I didn't see any consensus on whether that theme cookie actually worked. I want the opposite of what they were asking (I never  want to see the soon-to-be-gone mobile view).

In the post on depreciation of the mobile view it says:

> Instead of maintaining both of these, we’re going to unship the mobile view and **opt everyone into the responsive views by default**. Along the way, we plan on improving the responsive views we show.

Did I misunderstand the timing of the responsive views becoming the default?

Comment: That info is indeed stored in a cookie. It expires every now and then for me. But usually it remembers my preference for 6-8 weeks at a time. Every site has its own cookie though, so they expire individually, and require to be set individually too.

Comment: @Luuklag Ok, which cookie? and why shouldn't it be inverted and have the non-deprecated view come up if there is no cookie?

Comment: What I understood is that they still didn't finish making all pages responsive, although that was planned to be finished last year IIRC, once that's done the entire mobile view will go.

Comment: @Luuklag Yes, I am aware that the mobile view is deprecated and not all pages are responsive. That doesn't have anything to do with forcing the "full site" view to be the default. Because SE appears to be forcing me to set a cookie or something, requesting the desktop site using my browser's functionality doesn't appear to work consistently either.

Comment: Yep, we're a little delayed but we're _inches_ away from those mobile views going away entirely. This will be `status-completed` soon enough. No more cookie woes in just a little bit, sit tight and thanks for the patience!

Comment: @Aaron Thanks, as is typical for me, as soon as I ask for help I can't reproduce the issue. Oh but then I post this comment , and I'm back in mobile view lol.

Comment: @ColleenV There are definite bugs in the code that decides if you're gonna be shown a mobile layout or not, but we've taken the stance that they aren't worth fixing if we're just gonna chuck those in the trash anyway  Sorry for getting caught in the in-between state!

Comment: @AaronShekey any insight how long 6-8 inches is in days or weeks?